# How to make Push up in and Push up out animation Transition?

Tags: java, android, animation

I need 4 transition effect, but i just know 2 transition and 2 other i dont know. the 2 transition animation I have know is:

push down in transition:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" > 
   <translate android:fromYDelta="-100%p" android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="900"/>
   </set>
```

and push down out transition:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="100%p" android:duration="1500"/>
   </set>
```

but I don't know how to make **push up in** and **push up out** animation transition, so can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I didnt understand, you want to combine them?

Comment: no, i mean i just want to know how to make push_up_in and push_up_out animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Push up in**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" > 
     <translate android:fromYDelta="100%" android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="900"/>
 </set>
```

**Push up out**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" > 
     <translate android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="-100%" android:duration="900"/>
 </set>
```